# getting Black Screen while while changing Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am facing the problem of black screen while changing the activity from one to another. I found the answer why this is happening but could not find the solution for it. When  I go from my playActivity to GameCompleteActivity from where I can go to next level while going to next level I am finishing the instance of playActivity and calling new Intent for the same PlayActivity because my all different level works in the PlayActivity , becoz of my requirement I have to finish the last playActivity to start new playActivity for the next Level . This is where I get lag or black screen while going to the next level i.e. after finish and again starting the playActivity it takes time.

I tried Transculent.Theme also but it did not work. AsyncTask also did not gave me the desired result

Now i thought I show some animation of activity fading or something that might hide my black screen behaviour ?

need help in solution ? ....thanks

Answer (score 5):

This usually means that the new activity is loading data in the UI thread, hence the screen stays black until everything is loaded up.

Consider moving the code that loads all the Activitys data (it's a game so I guess the level & graphics) in a separate thread and then lets the PlayActivity know when the data is ready to use.

Comment: ok I will try to put things again on AsyncTask hope it helps .... and will get back to you ...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Such kind of thing Happens Remember to Debug when new Activity is called.

While making any Game, try to make partitions of different different Modules. So gets Easy to Trace your Problem.

Comment: I will try to maintain that ? I really need to debug it hard otherwise I guess i need to put animation before my activity starts thatz d only way left for time being ...

Comment: @user1169079: Debug because of Animation effect and so it gets a clear idea of where u stand.

Answer (score 0):

If you have heavy UI related code in your onCreate just try to do outside the onCreate by creating some function IntializeUI () and or maybe try to divide it in modular or else the use Transculent theme for your activity ...

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple bug: just make in your manifest file property to your activity:  android:theme="@android:style/ ... - and make it Translucent.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible that too much activity on the main thread will do this, in my experience the most common / noticeable cause is calling finish() immediately after startActivity() when transitioning.  Not saying it's wrong to do this, but if you want to get rid of the black screen you may need to try another approach such as using **noHistory**.